# Difference between "trust", "trust in", and "trust on"

Tags: prepositions, difference, sentence-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I don't know the exact meaning of these sentences.

1. I trust you.
2. I trust in you.
3. I trust on you.

I have heard all these sentences. But usually use the 2nd one whenever I need to say it to someone.

Answer (score 10):

According to [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/trust_2), *Trust in* is a phrasal verb which is formal and means *to believe in someone or something* as in

> We trust in God.

*Trust* means *to believe that someone is honest or will not do anything bad or wrong* as in

> I just don’t trust him.

When you trust someone for example you tell them your secrets.

However, *trust* can mean the same as *trust in* in the sense *to be sure that something is correct or right* as in

> I trust his judgement completely.

About *trust on*, I'm not sure I've even heard of such collocation. I think it doesn't exist at all at least in dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks you Azad for the very well explanation. Now I know that the 3rd one is completely wrong and how to use the 1st one and the 2nd one.

Comment: Glad you found it useful 

Comment: No problem. Keep up the good work!

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the URL to your source. (Providing links is recommended.) I hope you don't mind. ;-)

Comment: Not at all, so kind of you thanks. Though I used the app on my cellphone so wasn't really up for mentioning the publication info. The link's gonna be quite handy from now on 

Answer (score 0):

You can trust ON that.

Meaning you can put your trust on that.

So the "on" does not refer to trust but to "that". On that.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? The previous answer seems to disagree with you.

Answer (score -1):

To my best of understanding, 'trust on' can be said to be a continuous act of trusting in something or somebody.